# How can I add custom validation rules to my plugin settings?

Tags: plugin-development, validation

I have a plugin that needs to perform some custom validation on one of its settings. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gist is, you will need to give your plugin a dedicated Settings model class, where you will have complete control over its validation rules and errors.

Here’s how to set that up:

1. Create a new Model class whose defineAttributes() method is based on your plugin's current defineSettings() method.

   ```php
   class Foo_SettingsModel extends BaseModel
   {
       protected function defineAttributes()
       {
           return array(
               'settingName' => AttributeType::String,
               // ...
           );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Give your plugin a getSettingsModel() function (instead of defineSettings()), which will return a new instance of your settings model.

   ```php
   class FooPlugin extends BasePlugin
   {
       // ...

       protected function getSettingsModel()
       {
           return new Foo_SettingsModel();
       }
   }
   ```

To perform the actual validation, you have **two options**:

1. Create a custom validator class (see the ones in craft/app/validators/ for examples), and make your plugin’s rules() method include it:

   ```php
   class FooPlugin extends BasePlugin
   {
       // ...

       public function rules()
       {
           $rules = parent::rules();
           $rules[] = array('settingName', 'Craft\Foo_CustomValidatorClassName');

           return $rules;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Override your plugin’s validate() method and just perform the validation directly from there:

   ```php
   class FooPlugin extends BasePlugin
   {
       // ...

       public function validate($attributes = null, $clearErrors = true)
       {
           $validates = parent::validate($attributes, $clearErrors);

           if ($attributes === null || in_array('settingName', $attributes))
           {
               // Perform custom validation here
               // ...

               if (!$settingNameValidates)
               {
                   $this->addError('settingName', 'Error message');
                   $validates = false;
               }
           }

           return $validates;
       }
   }
   ```

Finally, the last thing you’ll need to ensure is that your plugin’s settings template is actually showing the error messages associated with this setting:

```twig
{{ forms.textField({
    ...
    errors: info.getErrors('settingName')
}) }}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this for a fieldtype that matches input against a regex (`PlainTextFieldType` plus input has to match the regex).

It has a `function validate` which checks that the input matches the regex when you try to save an entry with this field type. Now I need a new validation to check that the regex to match against is valid, which should prevent you from saving the field. Does that use the same `function validate`?

Comment: I'm closer. There are two `validate` functions. The one in `...FieldType.php` that validates entries with this field type, and the one in `...SettingsModel.php` that validates the actual field type.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant If you're still having trouble, it's probably worth posting a new question about it.

Comment: I had to change `extends Plugin` to `extends BasePlugin` and `extends Model` to `extends BaseModel` to get this to work - otherwise I was getting errors.