# Custom validation rules on frontend form

Tags: form, validation

What would be the best way to add some custom validation rules on forms submitted on the front-end without using specific field types for it?

I'm using the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin that allows anonymous posts to the targeted section.  I'm new to Yii and Craft CMS and I cannot seem to find a way to extend the validation rules for the [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel) (at least I suspect it needs to get done there).

Answer (score 1):

If your validation rules are truly custom and aren't covered by the default Craft validation rules, the only way I can think of getting them into the Guest Entries `EntryModel` is to fork the plugin and add your own `MyPluginEntryModel` that extends `EntryModel` adding a `rules` method with your custom validation logic.

Read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) for more details on that.

Comment: I found this question really helpful with adding custom validation in a plugin scenario: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10163/643