# Validating date fields in a plugin's settings

Tags: plugin-development, validation

I have a plugin that has some settings, some of which are dates. I want to make these fields required, and ensure they are valid dates.

Because of [this bug](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/how-do-i-save-a-plugins-date-settings-field) the date attributes are set as `AttributeType::Mixed`.

I'm using a structure like [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/custom-validation-for-plugin-settings) and [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/how-can-i-add-custom-validation-rules-to-my-plugin-settings) to set up the attributes on my settings, but I can't get the date fields to be required, never mind use a custom date-validation method.

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class My_SettingsModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'myText' => array(AttributeType::String, 'column' => ColumnType::Text),
            // There are multiple date fields, but for the example:
            'myDate' => array(AttributeType::Mixed),
        );
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules[] = array('myText', 'required');
        $rules[] = array('myDate', 'required');
        $rules[] = array('myDate', 'validDateString');

        return $rules;
    }


     public function validDateString($attribute, $params)
     {
         if ( /*  $this->$attribute is not a valid date  */ )
         {
             $this->addError($attribute, 'Please enter a valid date');
         }
     }
 }
```

`myText` is required OK - the form re-displays with an error message if you try to leave it empty.

I have two problems:

1. `myDate` is not required - if I leave the date field empty, the form is always successfully submitted, and when I go back to it the field has the date that was previously there.
2. Ignoring that, although `validDateString()` gets called, and doing `var_dump($this->$attribute)` looks something like `array(1) { ["date"]=> string(0) "18/01/2016" }`, I get "Illegal string offset 'date'" if I try to access `$this->$attribute['date']`. I'm baffled.

Comment: Incidentally, the data coming back as an array with a `"date"` key because I'm having to manage the date fields [like this](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/how-do-i-save-a-plugins-date-settings-field/8358#8358).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that because I'm now using my own settings model, I don't need to use `AttributeType::Mixed` for my date fields any more. (Thanks to carlcs for suggesting this.)

So I've removed the stuff [I had in my Plugin's `getSettingsHtml()`](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/how-do-i-save-a-plugins-date-settings-field/8358#8358), which massaged the fields before sending them to the template. And now, in theory, I only need to do this:

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class My_SettingsModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'myText' => array(AttributeType::String,
                            'column' => ColumnType::Text, 'required' => true),
            'myDate' => array(AttributeType::DateTime,
                            'column' => ColumnType::DateTime),
        );
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules[] = array('myDate', 'date',
                        'format' => array('dd/MM/yyyy'),
                        'allowEmpty' => false,
                        'message' => 'Please enter a valid date');

        return $rules;
    }
 }
```

However, although the form requires me to enter dates - it doesn't accept empty fields - it won't accept the dates I'm typing in. e.g., if I enter `31/12/2016` it fails the date validation. Looking at Yii's [date validation docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser) I think this should work...